# .ssh/config way to specify pseudo-tty allocation and command execution

Tags: ssh, configuration, gnu-screen

Is there any way to specify, in `.ssh/config`, a command like:

```
ssh -t remote-host "screen -dR screen_name"
```

so I can easily access the remote `screen` session with `ssh remote-host`?

Right now I solved this problem using a custom script:

```
$ cat ~/bin/sssh 
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/ssh -t $1 "screen -dR ab"
```

`~/bin` stays first at `$PATH`, but it is unflexible and ugly.

Also I would like to find way to implement host autocompletion for my custom script.

Comment: I would replace `$1` with `$@`. Then you can add more options, not just the hostname. For completion, try executing `. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh` , followed by `complete -F _ssh sssh`

Answer (score 31):

To allocate the tty as you would with the `-t` option, put `RequestTTY force` as an entry in the ssh config file (usually in `~/.ssh/config`). To always execute a command on the server after you've connected, put `RemoteCommand COMMAND` in the entry, where `COMMAND` is the command you'd like run upon connection. For other options, check `man ssh_config`.

```
Host remote-host
    Hostname my.server.com
    User imauser
    IdentityFile /path/to/identity_file
    RequestTTY force
    RemoteCommand screen -dR screen_name
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the force, Luke!

`RequestTTY force` in your `~/.ssh/config` for the desired host.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that this is the most flexible way.  A script allows you to set up parameters, add conditionals, change the command as needed, all based on the inputs.

There are ways to "force" the command in `authorized_keys`.  But I don't know of a way to force tty allocation except from the command-line or to force a command on the remote server from the local side config files.

Myself, I have a script that scans the config file, checks against DNS with various domains and sets the terminal emulator's title string.  I call it from screen on my local system (<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Note: `RemoteCommand` starts working with [OpenSSH 7.6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354594/remote-command-in-ssh-config-file). In earlier version (ie current debian 9.9) the ssh client will stop working properly (at least with `git pull`).