# How to configure SSH with a RemoteCommand only for interactive sessions (i.e. without command, or not sftp)

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-config

Currently I use Fish as my main shell on local and remote hosts.

I connect to remote hosts via ssh and sftp. I wanted to open or reuse a remote tmux whenever I connect, automatically, by default; so I added this to my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host example.com
RemoteCommand tmux a; or tmux
RequestTTY yes
```

The problem is that now I cannot connect through `sftp`, nor can I run a direct command from my local CLI:

```
➤ ssh example.com ping localhost
Cannot execute command-line and remote command.

➤ sftp example.com
Cannot execute command-line and remote command.
Connection closed
```

So, my question is: **How can I define a default command to be executed when opening a new interactive SSH session, but make it overridable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer directly the question. However it has become for me the fix to the root problem, so I think it deserves a post.

What I really wanted is to auto-enter tmux. Instead, I just started using byobu, which builds on top of tmux but is way more comfortable. For example, it supports this use case out of the box.

After installing byobu, just run:

```
byobu-enable
```

And you're done. Next interactive session will enter byobu automatically, no matter the shell. Non-interactive connections will work as usual.

Answer (score 15):

Option 1 )

You can the option Match ( see [man ssh_config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Match) )

```
Match Host example.com exec "test $_ = /usr/bin/ssh"
     RemoteCommand tmux a; or tmux
     RequestTTY yes
```

This will only differentiate difference between ssh & sftp

Option 2

You create some placeholder config for your diffe command , example :

```
Host tmux.example.com
  HostName example.com
  HostKeyAlias example.com
  RemoteCommand tmux a; or tmux
  RequestTTY yes
```

And after you can still use example.com for you sftp / ping usage .

Comment: 1st option didn't work. It seems Fish doesn't export `$_`. However, I can manually export a variable with `set -x auto_tmux 1` and change the match test to `"[ 1 -eq $auto_tmux ]"`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find an answer that worked for me: change the match to `Match exec "[[ $(ps h o args p $PPID | wc -w) -eq 2 ]]"`. That exec is true when ssh is invoked as "ssh <server>" but false if invoked as, say, "ssh <server> <command>"

Comment: if you have multiple hostnames nomrally space-separated like `Host with.example.com multiple.example.com` and you wish to use `Match` this way, try curly braces: `Match Host {with.example.com,multiple.example.com} exec "..."`

Comment: @rymo, I wasn't able to get that working with OpenSSH 8.0p1, dated 2019-05-28. Wasn't able to find *any* way to match on multiple hostnames with that version, except by adding it to the `exec` portion: `Match exec "[[ %n == @(pihole|router|athena|nas) && $(ps h o args p $PPID | wc -w) -eq 2 ]]"`.

Comment: @cryptarch, I really like your answer, but I couldn't find a way to apply it to a Windows client.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Autumn You'll probably want to check the manual for ssh_config. In particular, the exec runs everything in the quotation marks in your shell. Therefore, you will want to carefully inspect the command and check that it works as expected in your shell. I never touch Windows, so beyond this you're on your own :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using something more complex that deals with ssh options and space in arguments:

```
Match exec "POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 xargs -0 getopt -o 46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYyB:b:c:D:E:e:F:I:i:J:L:l:m:O:o:p:Q:R:S:W:w: --  </proc/$PPID/cmdline | perl -pe 's|.*? -- ||' | { read -r c; eval a=($c); [ ${#a[@]} -le 2 ]; }"
    RemoteCommand my-command-here
    RequestTTY yes
```

Also, if someone wants to use RemoteCommand for some machines (like inside "host xxxx"), the same trick can be used in reverse logic (match are evaluated after host):

```
Match exec "POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 xargs -0 getopt -o 46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYyB:b:c:D:E:e:F:I:i:J:L:l:m:O:o:p:Q:R:S:W:w: -- </proc/$PPID/cmdline | perl -pe 's|.*? -- ||' | { read -r c; eval a=($c); [ ${#a[@]} -gt 2 ]; }"
     RemoteCommand none
     RequestTTY auto

Host machine1 machine2 ...
     RemoteCommand my-command-here
     RequestTTY yes
```

If someone is curious, I'm currently using RemoteCommand to call screen:

```
RemoteCommand which screen &>/dev/null && TERM=xterm screen -q -RR "%u-%C" $SHELL -l || $SHELL -l
```

Comment: What's that supposed to do?

Comment: Parses ssh args in a space/quotes-safe manner, ignores any valid ssh opt (including opt value when required) and count if the remaining args are only two ("ssh" and "host"). It's similar to @cryptarch solution but also considering extra ssh opts.

Comment: Ssh could save us some pain if it simply consider command in cmdline to have higher precedence than -o RemoteCommend

Comment: This doesn't work with Fish, my main shell, as explained in the question :/

Comment: You can add "| tee /dev/stderr" before "perl" to check what it outputs. It might need a new kind of filter

Comment: It fails to process any ssh command with more than 1 parameter, like `ssh -v`.  Also, it doesn't support sh.
Mine supports sh, and uses hostname to check:
`Match exec "POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 xargs -0 getopt -o 46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYyB:b:c:D:E:e:F:I:i:J:L:l:m:O:o:p:Q:R:S:W:w: -- </proc/$PPID/cmdline | perl -pe 's|.*? -- ||' | tee /tmp/ssh_match | bash -c ' echo %h >> /tmp/ssh_match; read -r c; eval a=($c); for (( i=0; i < ${#a[@]}; i++ )); do [[ ${a[$i]} == '%h' ]] && break; done; (( i++ )); echo $i ${#a[@]} >> /tmp/ssh_match; [ $i -lt ${#a[@]} ]; m=$?; echo $m >> /tmp/ssh_match; exit $m '"`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to make a symlink alias to the `ssh` command:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ssh $HOME/bin/ssht
```

To make life easier, make sure `$HOME/bin` is in your `$PATH`.

In your ssh config:

```
Match Host example.com exec "test $_ = $HOME/bin/ssht"
     RemoteCommand tmux new-session -A -s mysession
     RequestTTY yes
```

Now, you can choose to use `ssht example.com` or `ssh example.com` for tmux and non-tmux sessions, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that worked for me.

It works for bash and fish

fish doesn't support $_ as @Yajo said

```
Match exec "ps --pid %%self -o ppid --no-headers | xargs -r ps ww --pid | grep /usr/bin/ssh"
  RemoteCommand tmux new -A
  RequestTTY yes
```

I used `tmux new -A` because my distant server supports tmux 3.1 and the automatic attach if session exists.

I had to use `%%self` to escape the % and be able to use %self.

Here is how it works

You ask to select the current process with `--pid %self`, but you ask to display your parent pid with `-o ppid`, then you ask to get only the value, and discard the header with `--no-headers`

so now you have the pid of what is supposed to be the ssh/scp/sftp command.

now you need to know, what command ran it.

`| xargs -r ps ww --pid` will launch `ps ww --pid YOUR_PARENT_PID`

The `-r` state for avoiding `xargs` to launch `ps` if the previous command matched nothing.

I'm using `xargs` and not `$()`, because fish doesn't support `$()` but `()` this difference would cause my code to work either in `bash` or `fish` but not both, so I'm using `xargs`

then we have the `ps ww --pid YOUR_PARENT_PID` :
`ww` will dump the full command line so here you can play with fgrep as I did or wc as @cryptarch did.